# Is there an API version of Accep.js of Authorize.net Accept.dispatchData(secureData, responseHandler)?

Tags: authorize.net, accept.js

I have a solution where the user will select a bundle of items and services where they come from different merchants.  One of the merchants requires the usage of Accept.js of Authorize.Net.
https://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/features/acceptjs.html
to obtain a payment nonce.

The Merchant provides me with a client Key and Login ID, used by Accept.js’s Dispatch Data Method, and by calling Accept.dispatchData(secureData, responseHandler) a payment nonce is returned.
I take this payment nonce and pass it to the Merchant through its API “PlaceOrder” call.

The issue with Accept.js is that it requires an input form on a website, where payment information (credit card) is intercepted and sent to Authorize.Net to generate the payment nonce.  Unfortunately, the payment information that I have is already stored in a database and I am unable to use a web form.  I must pull the data from the database, and send the payment information programmatically directly through API to Authorize.Net to get a payment nonce.  I cannot find such an option.  Is this possible?
For example:

```
merchantProduct = GetMerchantProduct()
ccInfo = GetCCInfoFromDatabase()
paymentNonce = AuthorizeNetGetPaymentNonce(MerchantKey, MerchantLogiID, ccInfo)
placeOrderToMerchant( merchantProduct, deliveryAddress, paymentNonce)
```

Comment: Accept.js was designed with PCI DSS in mind, for merchants who don't "touch" or store payment data, if you're storing payment data, l don't think Accept.js is for you. You can simply submit a create transaction request using the stored data, not sure what you need the nonce for.

Comment: If I could, I would not use Accept.js, but I am dependent on a third-party, the Merchant. The Merchant "forces" me to use Accept.js.  It is the only way I can submit orders through the Merchant.  In any case, I found a solution that is a bit convoluted, but nevertheless it works.